# Load special characters in AWS Spectrum Table

Tags: character-encoding, amazon-redshift, special-characters, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to create an external `Spectrum` table on top of plain text files but some values are considered as null because they contain special characters.

Create statement:

```
create external table s.table_1
(
    id bigint,
    city varchar(100)
)
partitioned by (file_date varchar(25))
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    with serdeproperties ('quoteChar'='\"', 'separatorChar'=';', 'serialization.format'='1') stored as
    inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
    outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://my_bucket/my_prefix/'
table properties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

But the results I am getting while selecting are:

```
id,city
1,<null>
2,<null>
3,Erfurt
4,Erfurt
5,Lahr
```

Instead of the expected:

```
id,city
1,Mönchengladbach
2,Mönchengladbach
3,Erfurt
4,Erfurt
5,Lahr
```

I tried to:

1. set `serdeproperties 'serialization.format'= '1'` or `'UTF-8'` or `'Latin-1'` or `'ISO 8859-1'`
2. set `row format delimited fields terminated by ';'` and change the `serialization.format` of `table properties`

but none of the above worked. I am just copying the file and it would suit me to load it without having to transform it in advance. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have a cluster to hand, but isn't text encoding set in the cluster properties?  maybe that influences Spectrum.  In any event, you've discovered one of the key reasons for not using Spectrum; silent errors.